# passing server side variable to linked javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am building a multilingual web application in which i have a .aspx.cs file

```
public partial class example:System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string message="message to be displayed depending on user language";
        public string Message
        {
            get{return message;}


            set{} 
         }    
}
```

and a .aspx file in which i have linked a javascript file for validating user input

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/DataValidation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return validation()">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSupplierName" CssClass="marginspace" runat="server" Width="150px" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                        onclick="btnSearch_Click"   />
</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my DataValidation.js file loks like this

```
 function validation()
    {
    var SupplierName = document.getElementById('tbSupplierName');
    if (SupplierName.value.length == 0)
    {
    alert('please enter supplier name');//here i want to display server side variable 'message'
    return false;
    }
    }
```

The problem is i want to pass my server side variable 'message' to the linked external javascript file DataValidation.js and display it in alert

I have tried below code but it is not working

```
function validation()
    {
  var message='<%=Message%>';
    var SupplierName = document.getElementById('tbSupplierName');
    if (SupplierName.value.length == 0)
    {
    alert(message);
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Help me to solve the problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare global JavaScript variable in your ASP.NET page

```
 <script>
    message='<%=Message%>';
 </script>
```

Then you can use it directly in JS file

```
function validation() {
    var SupplierName = document.getElementById('tbSupplierName');
    if (SupplierName.value.length == 0) {
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Satpal for helping.will there be any problem declaring global variable?